# Modeling transportation algorithmusing R(north west corner method)

Tags: r

I am new to R and I model transportation problem using R(north west corner method) codes are given below. each time i run the R script gives me

```
Error in if (requir[y] > supply[x]) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In unit[x][y] = supply[x] :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

error message and warning message.please help me to debug the code.

```
#cost data
cost=matrix(c(6,11,16,9,10,12,16,7,10),nrow=3,ncol=3)

#matrix to store amount flow between destinations
unit=matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
supply=c(200,200,200)

requir=c(150,200,250)

cost_minimum=0

x=1
y=1
while(x<4 & y<4){
    if(requir[y]>supply[x]){
        unit[x][y]=supply[x]
        requir[y]=requir[y]-unit[x][y]
        supply[x]=supply[x]-unit[x][y]
        cost_minimum=cost_minimum+unit[x][y]*cost[x][y]
        x=x+1
    }

   if(requir[y]<supply[x]){
      unit[x][y]=requir[y]
      requir[y]=requir[y]-unit[x][y]
      supply[x]=supply[x]-unit[x][y]
      cost_minimum=cost_minimum+unit[x][y]*cost[x][y]
       y=y+1
   }

  if(requir[y]==supply[x]){
      unit[x][y]=requir[y]
      requir[y]=requir[y]-unit[x][y]
      supply[x]=supply[x]-unit[x][y]
      cost_minimum=cost_minimum+unit[x][y]*cost[x][y]
      y=y+1
      x=x+1
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to come right out and ask: did you even bother trying to read the documentation before posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Stack Overflow is not a generally code debugging service. You should ask a specific programming question and provide a minimal example that clearly recreates and demonstrates the problem you are facing. You clearly have not yet isolated the error.

But your problem has nothing to do with any traffic algorithm; you just have basic syntax and logic problems. Pimarily you are indexing matirixes wrong

```
#wrong
unit[x][y]
#right
unit[x, y]
```

Secondly, inside your `if` conditions, you increment `x` or `y`. Then, in subsequent `if` statements within the same loop, you look for those new values which now may be out of the range 1-3. It seems like you should set them up as an `if/else` block so you don't walk off then end of the array. For example

```
while(x<4 & y<4){
    if(requir[y]>supply[x]){
        ...
        x=x+1
    } else if(requir[y]<supply[x]){
        ...
        y=y+1
    } else  if(requir[y]==supply[x]){
        ...
        y=y+1
        x=x+1
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 "Stack Overflow is not generally a code debugging service"

Answer (score 0):

Data frames are not matrices. If `unit` were a data frame, you could do `unit[[x]][y]` instead of `unit[x, y]`. That is because data frames are really just lists, where each column in the data frame is one element of the list. So you can use list syntax on them to access the columns. Matrices, however, are not lists. Internally, they are atomic vectors ("atomic" basically meaning "you can't access elements with the `$` operator") that are "stacked" by column. So a matrix `a <- matrix(100:103, nrow = 2)` is stored as `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` along with a special dimension attribute. To see this for yourself, type `dput(matrix(100:103, nrow = 2))`, and note the attribute `.Dim`. So `a[3]` and `a[1,2]` will both return `102`.

Note that even if `unit` were a data frame, `unit[x][y]` would still give you the wrong thing. `[` and `[[` are not synonymous. There are several differences, but most important is that they return different things when called on a list. `[` will return a list, in this case of length 1, whose elements are vectors. `[[` returns the vector itself. To help understand the difference, try the following code:

```
data(iris)  # "Iris" is one of R's built-in data sets.
sprintf("class of iris[1]: %s\nclass of iris[[1]]: %s\n",
        class(iris[1]), class(iris[[1]]))
sprintf("length of iris[1]: %s\nlength of iris[[1]]: %s\n",
        length(iris[1]), length(iris[[1]]))
```

For homework: what happens if you call `[[` on a matrix? Why is that different from calling `[[` on a data frame?